# PHP fread() expects parameter 1 to be a resource, boolean given

Tags: php, fopen, fseek, feof

I have this errors, the thing is on local server is working just fine, but now when i uploaded the files to the hosting i get these errors.

- fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
- fseek() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
- feof() expects  parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Some help needed..

PHP Script:

```
public function getDuration($use_cbr_estimate=false)
    {
        $fd = fopen($this->filename, "rb");

        $duration=0;
        $block = fread($fd, 100);
        $offset = $this->skipID3v2Tag($block);
        fseek($fd, $offset, SEEK_SET);
        while (!feof($fd))
        {
            $block = fread($fd, 10);
            if (strlen($block)<10) { break; }
            //în căutarea pentru 1111 1111 111 (biți de sincronizare a cadrelor)
            else if ($block[0]=="\xff" && (ord($block[1])&0xe0) )
            {
                $info = self::parseFrameHeader(substr($block, 0, 4));
                if (empty($info['Framesize'])) { return $duration; } //unele fișiere mp3 corupte
                fseek($fd, $info['Framesize']-10, SEEK_CUR);
                $duration += ( $info['Samples'] / $info['Sampling Rate'] );
            }
            else if (substr($block, 0, 3)=='TAG')
            {
                fseek($fd, 128-10, SEEK_CUR);//sărim peste dimensiunea etichetei id3v1
            }
            else
            {
                fseek($fd, -9, SEEK_CUR);
            }
            if ($use_cbr_estimate && !empty($info))
            { 
                return $this->estimateDuration($info['Bitrate'],$offset); 
            }
        }
        return round($duration);
    }
```

Comment: if `$fd` is a boolean, it means the file couldn't be opened. (The reason for that isn't going to be apparent from this code, though.)

Comment: Have you checked if the file actually opens or not???  Have you check `fopen` documentation?

Comment: It's part of programmer's job to debug.  Comment out `$duration=0` to all the way after `return round($duration)`.  Then just check the value of `$fd`.

Comment: I think the most likely possibility is that you're trying to store your files in an inaccessible directory on the hosting server that was accessible on your dev server.

Comment: @Eric the file doesn't open. The errors already tell us that. The only way a boolean can be passed to fread, etc. is if fopen fails and returns false.

Comment: I'm new with this, and i don;t have the knowledge .. if someone could help me..

Comment: @Don'tPanic , yes, that i'm trying to do

Comment: it's a good idea to do a `file_exists()` before running `fopen()` to make sure your path is correct in the first place. Print the file path and you will see your problem

Comment: Can you show me how please?